# GITLAB API Manage

Tags: api, gitlab

I'm trying to generate some issues via GITLAB API but I'm getting some problems that so far i was not able to overcome. Maybe you can point me in the right direction:

curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/issues?title=Testing2&labels=bug&description=HELLO

I want to create the issue with the title: Testing2,
Assign the label: bug,  Add the description: Hello

And I would like to do it in one command what am i doing wrong?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thank-you

Comment: url (with parameters) has to be a string, otherwise special characters like `?`, `=` or `&` will be interpreted by shell before passing url to curl.

Comment: I already tried that but for some reason it didn't work. But I will give another try. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @rsm you are absolutely right. IT works if i pass it as a string. Thank-you!